# Parse number via regex from html

Tags: php, regex

I am using `php 7.4.1` and want to parse a html string via regular expressions.

Find below a sample of my string (my exact string is much longer):

```
<?php

$string = ["<table role=\"presentation\" width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tbody><tr><td class=\"col\">
                                            <div>
                                                <img  editable=\"\" label=\"Article Image\" class=\"full-width-sm\" alt=\"{daily-news_title:23489}\" src=\"http://test.com/2020/03/200320134031-super-tease.jpg\"  style=\"width:600px;border: 0;line-height: 100%;max-width: 100%;vertical-align: middle\" width=\"600\"></div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr><tr><td class=\"spacer\" height=\"24\"></td>
                                    </tr><tr><td class=\"col px-sm-16\" style=\"padding: 0 24px;\" align=\"center\">
                                            <h2 class=\"webfont h2\" style=\"color: #232323; font-size: 28px; line-height: 30px; margin: 0 0 16px;\">
                                                {daily-news_title:23489}</h2>
                                            {daily-news_content:23489}
</td>
                                    </tr></tbody></table>                                <table role=\"presentation\" width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tbody><tr><td class=\"col\">
                                            <div>
                                                <img  editable=\"\" label=\"Article Image\" class=\"full-width-sm\" alt=\"{daily-news_title:23491}\" src=\"http://test.com/2020/03/106454487-1584734982506gettyimages-1207608097.jpeg\"  style=\"width:600px;border: 0;line-height: 100%;max-width: 100%;vertical-align: middle\" width=\"600\"></div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr><tr><td class=\"spacer\" height=\"24\"></td>
                                    </tr><tr><td class=\"col px-sm-16\" style=\"padding: 0 24px;\" align=\"center\">
                                            <h2 class=\"webfont h2\" style=\"color: #232323; font-size: 28px; line-height: 30px; margin: 0 0 16px;\">
                                                {daily-news_title:23491}</h2>
                                            {daily-news_content:23491} 
</td>
                                    </tr></tbody></table>"];

preg_match('/{daily-news_title:[0-9]*/', 'ac', $matches);


var_dump($matches);
```

Desired result

```
["23489", "23491"]
```

My above `$matches` variable is empty, however I would like to get the ids as following: `["23489", "23491"]`.

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: `'ac'` - what is it?

Comment: Why are you encapsulating all of that code into an array for?

Comment: I don't know php I'm afraid, but for the regex perhaps https://regex101.com/r/DxH1Ow/1.  I've checked this on python with `re.findall(r'<h2.*?news_(?:content|title):(\d+)', string)` and it returns `['23489', '23491']`.  If it's not working that check on the php side which I cannot be of help on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do it using the DOM and `sscanf()`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodeList = $xp->query('//td/h2[contains(@class, "webfont")]');

$result = [];

foreach($nodeList as $node) {
    list($result[]) = sscanf(trim($node->nodeValue), '{daily-news_title:%d}' );
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/YFbeC)

<sub>*(there is more than one way to cook a reindeer)*</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Use non-capturing groups. There's no need to reference the DOM.

1. Use _preg_match_all()_, not preg_match().
2. The mysterious 'ac' in your question seems to be a typo; that's where the input string, $html should be.
3. Also, you want only the second element of the *matches[]* array

   In short: 
   `preg_match_all('/(?:{daily-news_title:)([0-9]*)/', $html, $matches);
   var_dump($matches[1]);`

   Demo:  https://3v4l.org/OVuU1